# not receive push notification - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotification

In my app i am trying to to receive push notification, i have created a certificate and converted it as `.pem` file to test in the terminal, and copied the  certificate to server,when i send the notification from server its not received at the device end.
My Code as Follow

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.


if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];

NSString *newString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];


    NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"regId=%@", newString] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<myurl>"]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}  }
```

server side code

```
 $message = 'Hello';
$badge = 3;
$sound = 'default';
$development = true;

$payload = array();
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => intval($badge), 'sound' => $sound);
$payload = json_encode($payload);

$apns_url = NULL;
$apns_cert = NULL;
$apns_port = 2195;

if($development)
{
 $apns_url = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apns_cert = '/path/to/cert/cert-dev.pem';
}
else
{
$apns_url = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
$apns_cert = '/path/to/cert/cert-prod.pem';
}

$stream_context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apns_cert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apns_url . ':' .    $apns_port, $error, $error_string, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);

//  You will need to put your device tokens into the $device_tokens array yourself
$device_tokens = array();

foreach($device_tokens as $device_token)
{
$apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apns_message);
}

@socket_close($apns);
@fclose($apns);
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all?  Does the request to Apple succeed?  If not, what's the error?  If it does, what is happening on the device?  Look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html for debugging steps.

Comment: When i send notification from server, it display "Deliver Successful" But device not receive any notification

Answer (score 1):

There may be some certificate issue in developer account,or may be your device is not added in provisioning profile. You can check it by recreating the provisioning profile.